# Data retrieve when execute "select column" in Mysql

Tags: mysql

For example, there is a table in mysql:
Table t: (A,B,C,D)

And rows in table t is:
row1: a1,b1,c1,d1;
row2: a2,b2,c2,d2;
.....

My question is when executing "select A,B from t",
Does the stroage engine need to load all rows' data(including column c1,d1) from disk into memory in order to generate "select A,B" result? Assumption all columns are fixed length instead of var char.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you do not `SELECT` the fields and they are not contained in a `WHERE` or `JOIN`, then they will not be loaded into memory for query processing. So if you have a massive blob field in your row and you don't select it or filter on it, then it won't be a factor.

If you ever wonder about what's going on with the internals of a MySQL query, check out the [`EXPLAIN`](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/) feature.

Comment: then my question will be" select A from table t where A>XXX". It will only need to deal with A's data?In order words, no matter how many columns in table t, the performance are the same? More irrelevant columns won't affect the performance, right? I know EXPLAIN, but I can't find answer to irrelevant column's influence.